# max min in linear programming

Tags: math, optimization, linear-programming

I need to solve

```
\max_x \min_y x^T M y
```

where `M \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}`, `x \in \mathbb{R}^m` and `y \in \mathbb{R}^n`.

Contrains are

```
 \sum_{i=1}^n y_i = 1
 \sum_{j=1}^m x_j = 1
```

I know, the way to get a around this, is to make use of the duality theorem.

My question is: What is the reason that `\min_y x^T M y` which says to be the reason, why duality is needed here?

a. Is it, because `\min_y x^T M y` is not linear? I don't why this is the case.
b. Is it, because `\min_y x^T M y` is not solvable using lin prog?
c. Is it, becaus of another reason?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the methodology and application of the mathematical technique called *linear programming*.  It is not, within the definition used on SO, a question about *programming*.

Comment: Can you clarify the linear program problem statement? What is the objective function and what are the constraints?

Comment: ^ agreed you should head over to CS

Comment: I would say cs.stackexchange.com or math.stackexchange.com. However, cross-posting is discouraged so please close or delete this question before posting on another site.

Answer (score 0):

For a fixed value of your variable `x`, then the problem `P(x)`:

`\min_y x^T M y` subject to: `\sum y_i = 1`

is indeed a linear problem (in the variable `y` only), and therefore can be solved by classical linear programming method.

The problem is that the solution function of this problem, that is the function (I denote it `f`) that associates `x` with the value of the problem `P(x)` is not linear; and you can see that the original (min-max) problem you want to solve is equivalent to:

`\max_x f(x)` subject to: `\sum x_i = 1`,

which is therefore not a linear problem.